# Magento + M2ePro. Send Email on Sale Order, forces invoice creation and sets Order as Paid

Tags: php, magento, m2e-pro

I'm using Magento and M2ePro extension in order to publish and manage products on eBay.

Someone buys product X, and pays by Bank Deposit.

When I synchronize Sale Orders with the M2ePro extension, then the order appears both on the extension list of orders, and on the default Magento Sales->Orders menu on the Admin.
But if I choose to "Send Email" from within the Sales Order, for my customer to review details, the Order is automagically set to Paid on the eBay list, and an Invoice is generated on Magento.

I do not want this to happen, but cannot find any setting that works, nor help con the M2ePro extenison plugin "forums".
Any ideas regarding this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am one of the M2E Pro developers.

Most likely, you are missing something. M2E Pro subscribed on event called sales_order_invoice_pay. Only this event may force M2E Pro to update payment status of order on eBay.

I believe that such event cannot be generated by simple email sending and I just checked it to confirm my assumption.

Comment: Thanks anon. The problem was another module, that had an observer for the same event, and then did some horrible things which resulted on M2E misbehaving.